# Can't display date-picker on input type text created dynamically

Tags: jquery, forms, input, datepicker

I have a form created dynamically and it has one input type text for displaying a date-picker. When I click on the input, the date-picker does not display.

```
    $('.btn-add-subject').on('click', function () {

        $('.add-edit-delete-subject-ctnr').append('<div class="add-subject-ctnr">');
        $(".add-subject-ctnr").append('<form id="add-datas-schedule">');

        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(` <label>Date du cours<label/>`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type="text" id="datepicker" />`);
        // $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(` <label>Jour<label/>`);
        // $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type = "text" value = "" id = "add-line" placeholder = "Jours (0 à 4)">`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(` <label>Matière<label/>`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type="text" value="" id="add-class" placeholder="matière">`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(` <label>Horaires<label/>`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type = "text" value = "" id = "add-time" placeholder = 'heures "ex: 9.00-10.30"'>`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(` <label>Salle<label/>`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type = "text" value = "" id = "add-room" placeholder = "salle">`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(` <label>Classe<label/>`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type = "text" value = "${nameClass}" id = "add-class-name" placeholder = "classe" disabled>`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(` <label>Professeur<label/>`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type = "text" value = "" id = "add-former" placeholder = "professeur">`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(` <label>Couleur<label/>`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type = "text" value = "" id = "add-color" placeholder = "couleur (en englais)">`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type="submit" class="confirm-update-cours-btn btn" value="Ajouter le cours">`);
        $(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type = "button" class="cancel-add-value btn" value = "Annuler">`);


        $('body').on('focus', "#datepicker", function () {
            $(this).datepicker();
        });

        $('.cancel-add-value').on('click', function () {
            $('.add-subject-ctnr').remove()
        })
    })
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work, datepicker not display

Comment: Thanks don't see. I removed the nesting and it still doesn't change anything, I just tried putting $('#datepicker').datepicker () but it doesn't work. Whether it's a class or an id

Comment: Can you add a basic html structure? I wipped one up and got it working, unless I oversimplified it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would really like to overhaul how you are doing that, to get it to work you can try below.

First, changing the ID to a class, since you can't have duplicate IDs (I would change the other input ids for the same reason).

Then since you are appending, grab the LAST `datepicker` field and use it to apply `datepicker`.

**changing:**

```
$(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type="text" id="datepicker" />`);
```

**to:**

```
$(".add-subject-ctnr form").append(`<input type="text" class="datepicker" />`);
```

**and changing:**

```
 $('body').on('focus', "#datepicker", function () {
     $(this).datepicker();
 });
```

**to**

```
$(".datepicker").last().datepicker();
```

Comment: thanks you'r code are good and my css do a problem then. I probably don't have the right method. I am a student in 1st year of front-end development. I would like show you then

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems:

- Your handlers are nested, every time you add a subject, it'll add a
  new one.
- The way you are matching elements  returns a collection, so
  when you append, it will append to *all elements* in the collection.

And `id`s should be unique, in this case you can get away with it, but I'd use a `class` instead.

Note: I added `bootstrap-datepicker`, it might not be the same library you are using but *shouldn't* make much of a difference.

```js
$('.btn-add-subject').on('click', function() {
  // Create a new subject
  let $new_subject = $('<div class="add-subject-ctnr">');
  // Append to this new element
  $new_subject.append('<form id="add-datas-schedule">');
  // Same thing, search the new form inside the element and append to it
  $form = $("form", $new_subject);
  $form.append('<label>Date du cours<label/>');
  $form.append('<input type="text" class="datepicker" />');
  // Rest of controls removed for brevity

  // Add to the container
  $('.add-edit-delete-subject-ctnr').append($new_subject);
});

// Move handlers outside other handlers
$('body').on('focus', ".datepicker", function() {
  $(this).datepicker();
});

$('.cancel-add-value').on('click', function() {
  $('.add-subject-ctnr').remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn-add-subject">Add subject</a>
<div class="add-edit-delete-subject-ctnr">

</div>
```